# Xaml: Itemssource binding + fallbackValue

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, itemssource

I've got a Listpicker with a DataBinding on the Itemssource-Property. Binding works fine. Now I want to define a FallbackValue. My problem is, that the FallbackValue is interpreted as a list: {'S','t','a','n','d','a','r','d'}, not as a single item 'Standard'. I'm looking for a solution to solve this problem. Any idea?

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listPicker" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" ItemsSource="{Binding Profilelist, ElementName=userControl, FallbackValue='Standard'}" SelectedIndex="0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fallback behaviour is correct as the target expects an array (and a string an usable as an array of chars). There is no easy way to specify an array for the fallback.

I would suggest binding to a ViewModel list, instead of directly to the other control, so you can specify whatever default you want in the list. It does mean an extra binding and a property on your ViewModel (or code-behind... *yuk*) but element binding is not designed to have a fallback array, only single values.

*If you can provide more code/Xaml I will be able to be more specific.*

Comment: Thanks for your answere. We already found a workaround, using a static ressource put the items as string array inside and bind this ressource on the fallback value.
But is there no (simple) way to define a fallback array in xaml?

Comment: Sounds like you already found the simplest non-code solution :)